# apply_filters/do_action tag characters limit

Tags: filters, hooks, actions, limit, characters

Does **apply_filters**/**do_action** `$tag` name have a characters limit? Can be any problems if the tag name is way too long? I ask this because I know that WP transients have a limit of [45 characters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_transient#Parameters).

FYI, this is the tag I'm referring to:

```
apply_filters( $tag, ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always thought that the memory size was the limit for the *string* length, but according to the [PHP documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

```
string can be as large as up to 2GB (2147483647 bytes maximum)
```

There is also the maximum allowed memory size (`memory_limit`) for the PHP script, to consider.

### Testing: Do not perform this on a production server:

You could always use the `str_repeat` idea from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/467187/2078474) to test it:

```
// Check the hook name size limit:

$long_hook_name = str_repeat( 'x', 1024 * 1024 ); // Adjust the size until you hit the roof!

add_action( $long_hook_name, function(){
    echo 'Greetings from the hook with a very long name';
});

do_action( $long_hook_name );
```

but only test this where it's safe (locally?) ;-)

The same should apply for the `add_filter()`, since `add_action()` is just a wrapper:

```
function add_action($tag, $function_to_add, $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1) {
            return add_filter($tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args);
}
```

according to the [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/plugin.php#L401).

Answer (score 1):

The `$tag` is used as a key in an [array](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), so it is converted to either a string or an integer. There is no maximum size for strings, the available memory is the only real restriction. The size of an [integer](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) depends on the platform:

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18, except for Windows, which is always 32 bit. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant `PHP_INT_SIZE`, and maximum value using the constant `PHP_INT_MAX` since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

Use strings for better readability. Don’t try to fill the memory. :)